# How to remove url links with specific domain name or strings

Tags: python

I have made a function to scrape websites. The function scrapes the website and fetches url inside a website.

> ```
> print links      #scrape()
> http://www.web1.to/something
> http://www.web2.gov.uk/something
> http://www.web3.com/something
> http://www.web4.com/something
> http://www.web5.com/something
> http://www.web6.com/something
> ```

while fetching it also retrieves unnecessary sites links or with strings **.rdf** which i want to remove.

```
  def scrape()
    .
    .
            links = re.findall('href="(http.*?)"', sourceCode)

            for link in set(links):                         
                if 'web1.to' in link:
                    pass
                elif 'web2.gov.' in link:
                    pass
                elif '.rdf' in link:
                    pass
                else:                       
                    return link
                    #print link; #it seems to work(*)

#this section which call scrape function and prints the links   
for web in scrape():
    print web
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have created this function which seems to work if i use print inside the scrape function(see the commented line #print link). But when I called it outside it only returns one url

> ```
> http://www.web6.com/something
> ```

I then removed the for loop

```
            if 'web1.to' in link:
                pass
            elif 'web2.gov.' in link:
                pass
            elif 'web3.com' in link:
                pass
            else:                       
                return link
```

used this modifed function to print from outside. The conditions I given here doesn't work and it prints all the websites.

I know i have made some logical error in codeing but I dont see it. can you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is returning the first valid link it finds. Try adding a new list at the top of your `scrape` function:

```
valid = []
```

Every time you find a valid link, append it to your valid links list:

```
valid.append(link)
```

When you have finished checking all links, then return your whole list:

```
return valid
```

Try something like this:

```
valid = []
for link in set(links):
    if 'web1.to' in link:
        pass
    elif 'web2.gov.' in link:
        pass
    elif '.rdf' in link:
        pass
    else:                       
        valid.append(link)

return valid
```

Comment: not working. it dose the same thing only prints one link.

Comment: @Eka Are you sure you got your indentation correct? Make sure that you return *after* your for loop has finished, not right after your append a valid link. I'll add an example now

Comment: You got it I made an indentation error. I put return under else statement. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
def scrape()
    .
    .
            links = re.findall('href="(http.*?)"', sourceCode)
            return links

links =  scrape()
for link in links:
    if 'web1.to' in link:
        pass
    elif 'web2.gov.' in link:
        pass
    elif 'web3.com' in link:
        pass
    else:                       
        print link
```

Case 2 :

You have removed for loop from inside and now trying to access `"link"` to check various conditions but `link` is not defined and hence you are getting error.